# Django/Python Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required

Tags: python, django, django-urls

article.urls.py :

`from django.conf.urls import url`

`from . import views`

`urlpatterns = [`

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/$',views.search_tag,name='search_tag'),
```

`]`

article.views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from article.models import Article
def search_tag(request,tag):
    try:
        post_list = Article.objects.all()
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request,'tag.html',{'post_list',post_list})
```

tag.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load custom_markdown %}
{% block content %}
<div class="posts">
    {% for post in post_list %}
        <section class="post">
            <header class="post-header">
                <h2 class="post-title"><a href="{% url "detail" id=post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

                    <p class="post-meta">
                        Time:  <a class="post-author" href="#">{{ post.date_time |date:"Y M d"}}</a> <a class="post-category post-category-js" href="{% url "search_tag" tag=post.category %}">{{ post.category|title }}</a>
                    </p>
            </header>

                <div class="post-description">
                    <p>
                        {{ post.content|custom_markdown }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <a class="pure-button" href="{% url "detail" id=post.id %}">Read More >>> </a>
        </section>
    {% endfor %}
</div><!-- /.blog-post -->
{% endblock %}
```

Why i got error like this?

```
ValueError at /tag/Python/
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9000/tag/Python/
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/template/context.py in __init__, line 18
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/weixiang/workspace/WebPy/my_blog',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/weixiang/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 21 Nov 2016 07:50:07 +0000
```

In the `url`, 'Python' as the parameter should send to the `search_tag(request,tag)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the request context dictionary in incorrect format.

Instead of

```
return render(request,'tag.html',{'post_list',post_list})
```

It should be

```
return render(request,'tag.html', {'post_list': post_list})
```